# How to test setTimeout function for 3 hours?

Tags: javascript

I want to perform some action, after 3 hours.i have written that code in setTimeout function.

now I want to test code and I can't wait for 3 hours, for each test.

so how I can test?

example : 
`setTimeout(function() {
    alert('PerformAction() called!!');
}, 10800*1000);`

**I tried by changing my system time.**

Comment: maybe set it to 5 seconds or something for testing?

Comment: ^-- This. Or get a time machine. Or do something else while it's waiting.

Comment: haha..thats funny..or any other hacks? if possible? I know code will work but just wanted to sure, as it gonna affect lots of users.

Comment: *"it gonna affect lots of users"* don't work on production environment

Answer (score -1):

```js
function doSomething() {
    var d = new Date(),
        h = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getHours() + 1, 0, 0, 0),
        e = h - d;
    if (e > 100) { // some arbitrary time period
        window.setTimeout(doSomething, e);
    }
    // your code
}
```

Comment: add a description to your answer